# Are heaven and pitri lok the same place?

Tags: heaven

Are heaven (swarg) and pitri lok the same place ? Or are they different place ?

And what about Narak ?

Comment: they are different

Comment: Obviously they are different. Swarg is in north of earth, devas reside there. Pitru Lok is in south of earth, ancestors reside there. Narak/Patala is also in south, sinners reside there.

Comment: @mar So, when ancestors go to heaven or hell ? Do ancestors even go to heaven or hell or they reside only in Pitru Loka ?

Comment: why should they go to swarg or narak ? those are not the only 2 locations. there is pitru lok, gandharva lok, yaksha lok, naga lok, any number of lokas one can go depending on karma

Comment: @mar So, we don't go to Swarg or Narak but to Pitri Lok ?

Comment: @river - can you comprehend what i wrote ? i said svarg and narak are not the ONLY locations. they can go to swarg or narak or pitru or any of other lokas